# SQL Server 2005 - How to take a record from one table and loop through another table looking for match

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 tables. for this example I will use only one users records.
The first table has the user name and an evaluation date as such:

```
USER  EVALDATE
--------------
bobr  6/7/2010
bobr  9/20/2010
bobr  9/21/2010
```

The above table needs to be joined against this user history table, which has the history of the ID's and the dates they were valid, to look for a match (the NULL date means current):

```
USER   STARTDATE   ENDDATE
----------------------------
bobr   2/20/2006   4/18/2010
bobr2  4/19/2010   9/7/2010
bobr   9/8/2010    null
```

What I'm trying to do in SQL Server 2005 is take the first record from the first table, loop it through the second table and when(if) the EVALDATE is within one of these date ranges and the IDs match, then flag that record from the first table as valid.

The current code takes the record from the first table and runs against all rows of the second table and kicks out a record for each invalid evaldate, so it kicks out a record when joined against the second table because the evaldate is not between the dates of the first record on the history table, even though the record is fine because the evaldate is between the start and end dates of the third record in the history table.

I hope this makes sense! In something like SAS I can create an array and loop through checking against each record in the history table. How do I do this in SQL? What I was trying to do was just update the first table with a flag if the records dates are invalid. Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  [USER]
       ,[EVALDATE]
       ,CASE WHEN ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    [UserStartEndDates] b
                    WHERE   [a].[USER] = [b].[User]
                            AND [EVALDATE] BETWEEN [STARTDATE]
                                               AND COALESE([ENDDATE],[EVALDATE])
                  ) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS [IsValid]
FROM    [Evaluations] a
```

Comment: This works! I added an AND statement in the where clause to check that the userids were matching and it seems to be doing what I need it to do. It seems so simple but I couldn't come up with it! Thanks Brad, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
Select  *
FROM    Users u INNER JOIN 
        UserHistory uh  ON  u.User = uh.User
                        AND u.EvalDate BETWEEN  uh.StartDate 
                                        AND     ISNULL(uh.EndDate, u.EvalDate)
```

**EDIT**

Try this for all values from `User`

```
Select  u.*,
        CASE
            WHEN uh.User IS NULL
                THEN 'Invalid'
            ELSE 'Valid'
        END Validity
FROM    Users u LEFT JOIN  
        UserHistory uh  ON  u.User = uh.User 
                        AND u.EvalDate BETWEEN  uh.StartDate  
                                        AND     ISNULL(uh.EndDate, u.EvalDate)
```

Comment: Except that this hides the evaluations that are invalid because the `USER` doesn't exit in one or the other table.

Comment: yes true, I need the original table to come out with all records and either be flagged as valid or invalid. This worked but it does take out the records that are invalid. Still, the code works! Thanks Astander!!

Comment: Change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN then, using CASE to check for existance. Will add that to the answer quick like X-)

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
select * from [table2] t2 
join [table1] t1 on t1.user = t2.user 
--or better yet the foreign key 
where t1.user = t2.user and t1.evaldate     
between t2.startdate and t2.enddate
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this one first but could not get it to work. maybe I misunderstood something about the code?

Comment: this will return all users in table2 that are also in table1 that have an evaldate between the startdate and the endate of table2. If the user is not in table 2, they will not show up. It could be I misunderstood your question.  What message did you get when it did not work?

Comment: Well it ran but when it came back I had 4 records: 3 records from the history table of the first record, one for each evaldate from the first table and then the last record from the history table merged with the 6/7/2010 record from the first table.